# Transitive module import statements

Tags: angular, typescript

In my `Angular 6` application, I have the `app.module.ts` file which imports a custom module:

```
import { AppGuiModule } from './app-gui.module';
...
imports: [
  AppGuiModule,
```

In turn, the `app-gui.module` file imports the form modules:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
imports: [
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
```

I thought that would be enough to use the `[(ngModel)]` form element.

But alas, that's not the case, and it gives me the error:

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
  <div>
    <label>name:
      <input [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="user.name" placeholder="name"/>
    </label>
  </div>
"): ng:///AppModule/UserComponent.html@6:13
```

Only if I also import the form modules from within the `app.module.ts` file, does the application load fine:

```
import { AppGuiModule } from './app-gui.module';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
imports: [
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  AppGuiModule,
```

Should I group all GUI related import statements in one module ?

Is there any way to achieve some transitive imports ?

Comment: You need to import FormModule in app.module.ts. So you won't need to import in lazy load modules or other modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the issue, indeed doing it in a transitive way like I was hoping to do. The thing that I was missing was having the form modules listed in the `exports` block of the `AppGuiModule` module.

Here is some pseudo source code:

The `AppGuiModule` module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ]
})
export class AppGuiModule { }
```

The `AppModule` module:

```
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppGuiModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that re-exporting is not transitive even if `export[]` is a superset of `import[]`; it is pseudo-inheritance at best --- bundle sizes can become quite large. I have found this useful, however, *exactly* for this case (re-exporting `FormsModule` in a [Widget Feature module](https://angular.io/guide/module-types)).

Answer (score 1):

*Angular modules do not inherit from imported modules for template related abstractions (pipes, components, directives).* They do, however, for services (via injector scopes). In this case, `ngModel` is a  *template* abstraction, because of this, you'll need to import `FormsModule` to get access to the public declarations (exports) therein.